# How to subclass custom UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to create a `UITableView` with 3 different custom `UITableViewCell`. They all share some common elements such as a `UILabel` that is called `questionLabel`.

I have three types of cells

- `OneTextFieldTableViewCell`
- `TwoLabelTableViewCell`
- `ThreeLabelTableViewCell`

I want these cells to inherit from a `FormTableViewCell` that share common UI elements like the `questionLabel` as mentioned above.

Code:

```
class OneTextFieldTableViewCell: FormItemTableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerTextField: UITextField!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

FormItemTableViewCell

```
class FormItemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

I am getting errors:

```
Cannot override with a stored property 'questionLabel'

Getter for 'questionLabel' with Objective-C selector 'questionLabel' conflicts with getter for 'questionLabel' from superclass 'FormItemTableViewCell' with the same Objective-C selector

Setter for 'questionLabel' with Objective-C selector 'setQuestionLabel:' conflicts with setter for 'questionLabel' from superclass 'FormItemTableViewCell' with the same Objective-C selector
```

Comment: Your variable questionLabel is already defined in your superclass. No need to mention it again. That's the whole point of inheritance. Your subclasses inherit the variables of its super classes.

Comment: @user965972 you should add answer, you are correct

Comment: @user965972 That seems to work. If you add an answer, I will accept it. I mainly added it in the subclasses because I did not realize you can connect IBOutlets to the super class :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `questionLabel` is already defined in your superclass. No need to mention it again. That's the whole point of inheritance. Your subclasses inherit the variables of its super classes.

IBOutlet, IBAction, IBDesignable are just labels. Doesn't matter where you add them in the inheritance tree. Once there, you have informed the compiler/Xcode that this is a "special" function or variable.

So if your class has a function `@IBAction func doStuff()` , you can override it as `override func doStuff()` and still connect to it from within IB. Same for overriding IBOutlet in case you want to add `willSet` or `didSet` or replace the getter/setter functions.